# How do I link modules in ghc?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a haskell program that uses Data.Set and Data.IntMap, what flags do I need to give GHC to get it to link those libraries in? Simple question, I know, but the man pages didn't help me and I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding [`--make`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/modes.html#make-mode) will tell GHC to find all the dependencies and do all the linking for you automatically:

> GHC will figure out all the modules in
>   the program by following the imports
>   from these initial modules. It will
>   then attempt to compile each module
>   which is out of date, and finally, if
>   there is a `Main` module, the program
>   will also be linked into an
>   executable.